# Necessitas SDK for android app with Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, google-cloud-messaging, qt-necessitas

There are 2 pages that confuse me:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-support.html

and

https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_Create_and_Run_Qt_Application_for_Android

Both these pages guide you on how to create Android apps with Qt. But one uses the Necessitas SDK and the other doesn't.

I want my app to use the Google-Cloud-Messaging service to be able to send and receive notifications.

I already have created an Android app and it runs fine on my phone without using the Necessitas SDK.

**So my question is: Do i need this necessitas SDK? if so, why? Or can i just continue like i already have?**

Comment: Is there anything broken on your end? If not, don't fix it.

Comment: @mah           Well, I am having trouble getting the Google-Play services installed correctly so that I can use the Google-Cloud-Messaging service. But aside from that everything seems fine. So i guess i should just continue as I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 2nd link is out of date.  From what I understand, necessitas was needed for Qt4 but Qt5 has it by default.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/27754/do-i-still-need-to-download-necessitas-when-using-qtsdk-5-1/3